# Azure PowerShell: How to verify that the input Storage Account belongs to some Subscription

Tags: azure, powershell

How can i verify that some Storage Account name (received as input) belongs to some specific subscription

```
$storageAccountName = <something from input>
$storageAccountKey = <something from input>

$subscriptionName = "MySubscription"
$subscription = Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName

$StorageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
```

**Now what?**

how can i verify that the given storage account really belongs to this specific subscription?

(In case it doesn't i want to exit the script and now allow to continue.)

Comment: Are you logging in the azure via powershell or you are just trying to fetch the subscription details using the AzureStorageContext based on StorageAccountName and AccessKey?

Comment: @AnishK "just trying to fetch the subscription details using the AzureStorageContext based on StorageAccountName and AccessKey". Thanks

Comment: You are trying to achieve the other way around i.e. trying to get the subscription details from the azure resource which is kind of impossible AFAIK. I am not sure about your use case but the storage account name always remain unique irrespective of any subscription. Please find the Storage Account Naming convention here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#storage which states that storage account name is 'globally unique name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acccording to my test, we can get all the storage account name in one subscription then we ensure if these names contain the name you provide. For example:

```
Connect-AzAccount 
$SubscriptionName=""
$Subscription=Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName  
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $Subscription

#get all storage account name in the subscription 
$name = Get-AzStorageAccount | Select-Object StorageAccountName


$StorageAccountName="test" 

$value=$name.StorageAccountName.IndexOf($StorageAccountName)

if($value -ne -1) {
   Write-Host " exist"
}else {
   Write-Host "does not exist"
}
```

**Update** 
[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Comparing the names is not secured enough! We can have two different subscriptions where each one has a storage account but they have same StorageAccountName

Comment: @Samer - Two storage account can never have the same name. You can verify the same by trying to create two storage accounts with same name in single/different subscription.

Comment: @SamerAamar according to my test, the storage account is unique. We can not use the same account name in single/different subscription

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer to this is:
Which resource group is it in, and in which subscription is the resource group then located:

```
$sa = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name <input storage account name>

$sa
StorageAccountName ResourceGroupName Location   SkuName     Kind      AccessTier CreationTime        ProvisioningState EnableHttpsTrafficOnly
------------------ ----------------- --------   -------     ----      ---------- ------------        ----------------- ----------------------
sa001           rg080        westeurope StandardLRS StorageV2 Hot        02/09/2019 15:16:15 Succeeded         False

Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $sa.ResourceGroupName -Location $sa.Location


ResourceGroupName : rg080
Location          : westeurope
ProvisioningState : Succeeded

ResourceId        : /subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/rg080
```

From there on you will be able to match the resourceid with the subscriptionid that you can find from

```
get-azurermsubscription
```

Something like so:

```
(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $sa.ResourceGroupName -Location $sa.Location).ResourceId.Split('/')[2] -like (Get-AzureRmSubscription | where name -like $subscriptionName).SubscriptionId
```

Comment: thanks. nice answer.
but i don't have resource name which is a mandatory parameter to the Get-AzureRmStorageAccount

Comment: This is from your code:`$storageAccountName = <something from input>
So, you're already giving it as input aren't you?

Comment: i get the storage account name and key from the user. so i have these two variables: $storageAccountName and $storageAccountKey

Comment: So you do have the resource name?

Comment: i have in hands: 
SubscriptionName, SubscriptionId, StorageAccountName and StorageAccountKey.

Do i have to request something else?

Comment: With all of that the above pieces of code are plenty for you to do what you want to do. Do you need to whole script written out completely, or what are you expecting/asking?

Comment: Thanks. With these peices i can manage. I still didnt confirm because of changes in priorities but i will get back to it. Thanks again